# appxUpload file not getting generated when creating UWP bundle file to upload on microsoft Store

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, appxmanifest

I am trying to create appxupload file to be uploaded to the Microsoft Store. But when i generate the bundle file along with appxupload file, only appx bundle file is getting generated whereas appxupload file is not generated. 
Also i followed the steps to associate my App with Microsoft store.
I have tried the following steps to generate appxupload file:
1) Associate app with Microsoft Store with my developer Account
2) Create appx Bundle file using Store --> Create App Packages and click Create button to generate appxUpload file to be uploaded to the Store.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking, and no evidence that you've tried anything yourself.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear, But my final query is how should i get appxupload file of my UWP app to be uploaded on Microsoft Store??
My app is already published in app store and this time i am trying to create next release/update version.

Answer (score 2):

Please choose **Always** in the **Generate app bundle** listbox. If you choose the **never** for **Generate app bundle** listbox, the Visual Studio will only generate .appx or .msix .You could refer to the following picture and the detailed steps provided in document: [To create your app package upload file using Visual Studio.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps#to-create-your-app-package-upload-file-using-visual-studio) for more details.

[image]